# How to detect processes that are using the sound card on Linux?

Tags: linux, process, soundcard

I was wondering if it's possible to get the processes that are using the sound card at a specific time. For instance, I just want to know if there is any song currently playing in Spotify or Chrome, whatever. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, a Linux application could be using via PulseAudio or directly accessing ALSA (Advanced Linux Sound Architecture) which forms the foundation of Linux Sound Architecture.

To see the processes utilizing ALSA, use the following command as root, 
`lsof /dev/snd/*`

You will mostly see that pulseaudio is utilizing these. Now, to see the apps using sound devices via PulseAudio use

```
pacmd
>>> list-clients
```

That should give you a list of apps accessing pulseaudio and the process ID should be visible there.